# Second DataGrid control in ASPX web form does not render data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Have two DataGrid controls in ASPX page.  The first control populates after setting datasource and calling DataBind().  However, the second control is not rendering the data.

Here's the markup:

```
<!--First DataGrid-->
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgPremiumHistory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemCommand="dgPremiumHistory_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="ID">
<Columns>asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Company Premium History ID" DataField="ID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Premium Year" DataField="PremiumYear" ReadOnly="True" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Amount" DataField="Amount" ReadOnly="True" />
<asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditPremium" /></Columns></asp:DataGrid>


<!--Second DataGrid-->
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgPayrollHistory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemCommand="dgPayrollHistory_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="ID">
<Columns><asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Company Payroll History ID" DataField="ID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Payroll Year" DataField="PayrollYear" ReadOnly="True" /><asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Amount" DataField="Amount" ReadOnly="True" />
<asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditPayroll" /></Columns></asp:DataGrid>
```

C# Code-behind:

```
protected void PopulateDgPremiumHistory(ref DataTable dt)
    {
        dgPremiumHistory.DataSource = dt;
        dgPremiumHistory.DataBind();
    }
    protected void PopulateDgPayrollHistory(ref DataTable dt)
    {
        dgPayrollHistory.DataSource = dt;
        dgPayrollHistory.DataBind();
    }
```

I'm calling the methods in Page_Load event.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt = pkg.getCompanyPremiumHistory(hfWCAppID.Value);

            PopulateDgPremiumHistory(ref dt);

            dt = new DataTable();
            dt = pkg.getCompanyPayrollHistory(hfWCAppID.Value);

            PopulateDgPayrollHistory(ref dt);
        }
```

Comment: Here's a breadcrumb -- was able to get the second control to render data after commenting-out code in Page_Load that calls the first method .  Very strange.

Comment: how to fill datatable parameter in methods?

Comment: Thanks Morteza.  Using ADO.NET to fill the DataTables.  Both are being populated with data from the database.  The problem seems to exist when attempting to set the data source and bind the data on the second DataGrid

Comment: please add code wich  to fill the DataTables

Comment: Code to popluate the DataTable is encapsulated within a dll unfortunately.  The tables do get populated with data though.

Comment: Why are you passing the `DataTable dt` parameter by-reference?

Comment: Please post the code that calls `PopulateDgPayrollHistory`.

Comment: Thanks Dai.  By reference just in case I have to modify the table in the preceding methods without altering the original object.  I posted the code in Page_Load.  Seems ASP.NET doesn't like multiple DataGrids in a page rendering at the same time (maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I had to use a work-around.  Placed the DataGrid controls in separate Panel controls.  Using a button-click event, I showed/hid the panels and simultaneously called the respective method to populate the DataGrid.